# Convert JSON to CSS with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css, json

I have some encoded JSON data stored in my database, like the following:

```
{".main-header":"{\"color\":\"rgb(5, 213, 255)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"NeutraText-Book\",\"font-size\":\"35px\"}",".main-header-free":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"NeutraText-Book\",\"font-size\":\"22px\"}",".sub-header-lunch-price":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"NeutraText-Book\",\"font-size\":\"22px\"}",".sub-header-week":"{\"color\":\"rgb(62, 214, 24)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"NeutraText-Book\",\"font-size\":\"22px\"}",".sub-header-week-week":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"NeutraText-Book\",\"font-size\":\"22px\"}",".day-name":"{\"color\":\"rgb(237, 129, 5)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"NeutraText-Book\",\"font-size\":\"22px\"}",".lunchtext":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"Baskerville\",\"font-size\":\"13px\"}",".puffheading":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"NeutraText-Book\",\"font-size\":\"22px\"}",".pufftext":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"Baskerville\",\"font-size\":\"13px\"}",".re_name":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"'Times New Roman'\",\"font-size\":\"13px\"}",".re_address":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"'Times New Roman'\",\"font-size\":\"13px\"}",".re_phone":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"'Times New Roman'\",\"font-size\":\"13px\"}",".re_webpage":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"'Times New Roman'\",\"font-size\":\"13px\"}","html":"{\"background\":\"none\"}"}
```

This is how I would do it with jquery:

```
var currentStyle = {{ $theme->css}};

$.each(currentStyle, function( index, value ) {
   $(index.toString()).css(jQuery.parseJSON(value)));
});
```

In my Controller, I render the view and then converts it to a PDF:

```
    $view = View::make('pdf.template')
                ->with('css', $css);

    $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($view);
    return $pdf->stream();
```

This means that the view rendered will return the DOM in its initial state, I cannot use any JavaScript to apply the JSON CSS with say jquery, because of that.

So can I directly convert this JSON to CSS through PHP somehow?

Comment: Have you tried to slip in a <style>your css here</style>

Comment: Updated question... Maybe you understand better now.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to generate valid css in your php script:

```
$str = '{".main-header":"{\"color\":\"rgb(5, 213, 255)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"NeutraText-Book\",\"font-size\":\"35px\"}",".main-header-free":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"NeutraText-Book\",\"font-size\":\"22px\"}",".sub-header-lunch-price":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"NeutraText-Book\",\"font-size\":\"22px\"}",".sub-header-week":"{\"color\":\"rgb(62, 214, 24)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"NeutraText-Book\",\"font-size\":\"22px\"}",".sub-header-week-week":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"NeutraText-Book\",\"font-size\":\"22px\"}",".day-name":"{\"color\":\"rgb(237, 129, 5)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"NeutraText-Book\",\"font-size\":\"22px\"}",".lunchtext":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"Baskerville\",\"font-size\":\"13px\"}",".puffheading":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"NeutraText-Book\",\"font-size\":\"22px\"}",".pufftext":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"Baskerville\",\"font-size\":\"13px\"}",".re_name":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"\'Times New Roman\'\",\"font-size\":\"13px\"}",".re_address":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"\'Times New Roman\'\",\"font-size\":\"13px\"}",".re_phone":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"\'Times New Roman\'\",\"font-size\":\"13px\"}",".re_webpage":"{\"color\":\"rgb(0, 0, 0)\",\"background-color\":\"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)\",\"font-family\":\"\'Times New Roman\'\",\"font-size\":\"13px\"}","html":"{\"background\":\"none\"}"}';
$arr = json_decode($str, true);
$css='';
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $css.=$key . '{' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach(json_decode($val, true) as $k => $v){
        $css.=$k . ':' . $v . ';' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $css.= '}' . PHP_EOL;
}
//to see result
//echo '<pre>' . $css . '</pre>';
$view = View::make('pdf.template')
            ->with('css', $css);

$pdf = PDF::loadHTML($view);
return $pdf->stream();
```

Then  in your view echo `$css` withing `<style>...</style>` tags.

Note that the new lines (PHP_EOL) are only for formatting, and are not needed.

Comment: If you try decode the string provides, you can see this fails, as it is isn't decoded that the element attributes are separated.

Comment: @user3121056 Sorry i dont understand what you mean